# SwiftUI: restrict extension to custom view struct / return custom view type

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, opaque-types

#### What I want to achieve:

```
CustomView()
    .doSomething() // ← should only be available on CustomView
    .doSomethingElse() // ← should only be available on CustomView

AnyOtherView()
    .doSomething() // ← should not compile
```

Pretty much like SwiftUI's Text implementation has that exact functionality:

[image]

#### What I tried

```
struct CustomView: View {
    ...
}

extension CustomView {
    func doSomething() -> some CustomView {
        self.environment(\.someKey, someValue)
    }

    func doSomethingElse() -> some CustomView {
        self.environment(\.someOtherKey, someOtherValue)
    }
}
```

I get the following error: ***"An 'opaque' type must specify only 'Any', 'AnyObject', protocols, and/or a base class"***.

#### What I also tried:

```
extension CustomView {
    func doSomething() -> CustomView {
        self.environment(\.someKey, someValue)
    }

    func doSomethingElse() -> CustomView {
        self.environment(\.someOtherKey, someOtherValue)
    }
}
```

I get the following error: ***Cannot convert return expression of type 'some View' to return type 'CustomView'***.
Xcode provides the following fix:

```
extension CustomView {
    func doSomething -> CustomView {
        self.environment(\.someKey, someValue) as! CustomView
    }
}
```

But force casting does not really look like a great solution.

How can I fix this?
I only want to extend `CustomView`. I don't want to extend `View` and return `some View` because that would expose functionality to all views (which is not what I want).
If I extend CustomView and simply return some View, then I cannot use both functions at the same time.

#### Edit: Why do I want to achieve that?

I am building up a Swift Package to provide `CustomView` to multiple projects.
And to make `CustomView` easy to use I wanted to make it configurable with view modifiers instead of a simple initializer.

I could use my provided `CustomView` like that:

```
CustomView(value1: someValue, value2: someOtherValue)
```

... but I wanted to make it more SwiftUI-Like in the way of optional view modifiers like that:

```
CustomView()
    .value1(someValue)
    .value2(someOtherValue)
```

That would look nice if I needed other view modifiers on that view like `tint(...)` or `fixedSize()`, etc. Much like you would configure `Text`, which you customize with view modifiers instead of the initializer, since customizing is optional.

Comment: Is the use of the environment key to your problem or is it just something you have tried?  You are using a view modifier patter in `CustomView().doSomething()` code, but you don't actually have a view modifier.

Comment: You should not compare this to `Text` in the first place. Your `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` is not comparable to `Text.italic` and `Text.bold` *precisely because* they do not return a `CustomView` like those two methods do. Your methods return whatever `environment` returns, which is not `CustomView`.

Comment: @Sweeper you are right. @ Paulw11 in my particular case, I actually want to use the environment key, however that is not the main part of the question. It should not matter what view modifiers i use. But i get that the view modifier returns a view – wich is not a custom view.

Comment: I still don't follow how you are expecting to use something from the environment as the return value. The view modifier pattern accepts a view as an input and returns some modified version of that view. It doesn't make sense to pluck some view from an environment object.

Comment: @Paulw11 the environment modifier is not the important part here. My question goes more in the architectural direction on restringing view modifiers to a certain view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As others have pointed out, you cannot pipe any modifier in your functions that have a return type other than your `CustomView`

With that said, you can do something like:

```swift
struct CustomView: View {
    @State var myBackground = Color.clear
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("Hello World!")
            .background(myBackground)
    }
}

extension CustomView {
    func customBackground(_ newBackground: Color) -> some CustomView {
        self.myBackground = newBackground
        return self
    }

    func clearBackground() -> some CustomView {
        self.myBackground = .clear
        return self
    }
}
```

And use it as needed:

```swift
struct AnotherView: View {

    var body: some View {
      VStack {
        CustomView()
          .customBackground(.blue)
          .clearBackground()
          .customBackground(.red)
           // ... and so on

        Text("Hi everyone!")
          .customBackground(.blue) // <--- this will fail compiling
      }
    }

}
```

But you cannot use any other modifier that erases your type. To reach your desired behavior, all the changes done in your functions/modifiers must be done only on properties accessible by your struct directly and have a return value that you guarantees is your view's type

Comment: This is good but didn't work for me until I removed the @State property wrapper.

Answer (score 1):

How do you know `environment` returns `CustomView`? You don't - what type it returns is an implementation detail of SwiftUI.  Your whole premise falls apart when you see that `environment` returns something like `ModifiedContent<CustomView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<T>>` (as shown in Ashley Mills' answer), doesn't it?

Let's inline `doSomething`:

```
CustomView()
    .environment(\.someKey, someValue)
    .doSomethingElse()
```

You are not calling `doSomethingElse` on `CustomView()` here - you are calling it on the return value of `environment`, and `environment` doesn't even return `CustomView`, so why should `doSomethingElse` be available?

One way to rephrase what you want is to keep track of the "root" of the call chain - a way to say "this method should be available on call chains that has `CustomView` as its root"

You can sort of do this by returning from `doSomething` a wrapper that also has the root's type, and adding the `doSomething` and `doSomethingElse` to also the wrapper types. But IMO this is really convoluted for what it's worth.

```
protocol ViewChain: View {
    associatedtype ChainRoot
}

struct WrappedViewChain<Body: View, ChainRoot: View>: ViewChain {
    let wrapped: Body
    let rootType: ChainRoot.Type
    
    var body: some View {
        wrapped.body
    }
}

extension CustomView: ViewChain {
    typealias ChainRoot = CustomView
}

extension ViewChain where ChainRoot == CustomView {
    func doSomething() -> WrappedViewChain<some View, CustomView> {
        WrappedViewChain(wrapped: environment(\.someKey, someValue), rootType: CustomView.self)
    }
    
    func doSomethingElse() -> WrappedViewChain<some View, CustomView> {
        WrappedViewChain(wrapped: environment(\.someOtherKey, someOtherValue), rootType: CustomView.self)
    }
}
```

This essentially made it so that `doSomething()` and `doSomethingElse` "remembers" the root of the chain in the second type parameter of `WrappedViewChain`.

Note that this still won't work if you make it "forget" the root somewhere along the way, but `Text` behaves like this too.

```
CustomView()
    .frame(width: 100) // forgets the root
    .doSomething() // now this doesn't work
```

```
CustomView()
    .doSomething() // OK
    .frame(width: 100) // forgets the root
    .doSomethingElse() // now this doesn't work
```

Comment: great answer, but yes, that is really convoluted. I update my question to give more context on why I want to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, I'm afraid, but an explanation.

The problem, as you've discovered, is that the result of

```
self.environment(\.someKey, someValue)
```

is *not* `CustomView`. The function doesn't modify the existing view, it creates a new one.

Let's say `.someKey` is an `Int`, then you can test this out as follows:

```
extension CustomView {
    func doSomething() -> some View {
        let newView = self.environment(\.someKey, 23)
        print(type(of: newView))
        return newView
    }
}
```

and you'll see that the actual returned type is

```
ModifiedContent<CustomView, _EnvironmentKeyWritingModifier<Int>>
```

This means that if you also declare `doSomethingElse()` in an extension on `CustomView` you won't be able to apply it to the result of `doSomething()`.

Nor can you force cast the result of `doSomething()` to `CustomView` as they are just different types, so it will crash.

Comment: I understand that explanation, but `Text` is doing the same thing. There are modifiers like `.bold()`and `.italic()` that only work on `Text` and return `Text`, so it has to work somehow.

Comment: `.bold()` & `.italic()` are functions on `View`, not `Text`. You can apply them, for example, to an `Image` or an `EmptyView`, etc

Comment: @WalterBeiter More accurately, there are two versions of `bold` and `italic` etc. The one that is defined on `Text` returns `Text`, and the [one](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/bold(_:)) that is defined on `View` returns `some View`.